# How to get all circles that intersect a given circle in PostGIS?

Tags: python, postgresql, geometry, postgis, intersection

I'm trying to find out all the circles stored in the database(The circles are present all over the world) that intersect or overlap a given circle. I've stored the circles like this:

```
CREATE TABLE circles(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, name varchar, code integer, the_geog geography(POLYGON,4326) );

INSERT INTO circles (gid, name, code, the_geog) VALUES (1,"hello", 11,geometry(ST_Buffer(geography(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(48.732084 -3.459144)')), 1000)));
```

Now when I'm trying to find out all the circles that intersect a given circle, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography.
```

I'm using this query to get the data:

```
select * from circles where st_intersects (circles.the_geog,ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-105.04428 39.74779)', 4326), 2877), 1500));
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using:

```
select * from circles where st_intersects (circles.the_geog,geometry(ST_Buffer(geography(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(13.28527 52.521711)')), 1000)));
```